# Is tcpdump a client of rpcpad and implemented in pcap?

Tags: networking, tcpdump, pcap

https://www.tcpdump.org/index.html#documentation has manpages for pcap, tcpdump, and rpcapd, but I don't find what relation is between the three.

Is pcap a C library for implementing a client of rpcapd?

Is tcpdump a client of rpcpad and therefore dependent on rpcpad?

Is tcpdump implemented in pcap?

Answer (score 5):

`pcap` is a packet-capture library; it provides a common interface for packet capture across a number of different operating systems.

`tcpdump` is implemented *using* `pcap`.

`rpcapd` is a remote packet-capture dæmon, also implemented using `pcap`; it allows packets to be captured on one host controlled by another. `pcap` can connect to `rpcapd`, and use it to capture packets; so `pcap`-based tools can be clients of `rpcapd` (but they don’t have to).

`tcpdump` depends on `pcap`, but neither depend on `rpcapd`; thus for example the `tcpdump`-related packets in Debian [don’t even ship `rpcapd`](https://bugs.debian.org/964985). If `pcap` is built with remote support, `tcpdump` can use that to connect to `rpcapd`.

Comment: Thank you. Is rpcpad implemented in pcap in order to capture packets? Can tcpdump be a client of rpcpad?

Comment: I think there's some confusion about names here (and in the question). Are rpcpad and rpcapd two different things, or similar names for the same thing?

Comment: Are the answers to my questions in my comment yes and no?

Comment: @Mary see the updated answer (using, not in; and yes).

Comment: I believe rpcap is the protocol for usage of rpcapd and for a pcap-based client (tcpdump, Wireshark) to support. rpcapd is the server/daemon that handles forwarding captures from its host to the remote client (using tcpdump or Wireshark, etc.)